# c# List<> select specific variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview (ASPxGridView) and i want to fill row.
My c# code is like this:

```
List<ProductEntity> productList;
productList = product.getProducts();
gvProducts.DataSource =...
gvProducts.DataBind();
```

I don't want to show all variable of ProductEntity, only names and price.

I know there are many ways but what is simplest, easiest way?

I tried something like this:

```
productList = product.getProducts().foreach()
```

But it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to show only specific **columns** or filter specific **rows**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result =product.getProducts().Select(x=> 
          new {Name = x.name ,
                  Price= x.price})
         .ToList();
```

Comment: There is a mistake. Should be Price = x.Price

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i can't find ".Select" method. Are you sure it is "List<>" type?

Comment: @ridvanzoro add  `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code I can't say for sure but if you only want to select name and price from your products...

```
List<ProductEntity> productList;
productList = product.getProducts()
                       .Select(p => new {  p.Name, p.Price });
```

edit: expanding on my code example to show a working test:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    namespace StackOverflow
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class ProductListQuestion
        {
            class ProductEntity
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public decimal Price { get; set; }
                public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
            }

            [Test]
            public void CanSelectProperties()
            {
                var products = new List<ProductEntity>
                {
                    new ProductEntity {Name = "First", Price = 1M},
                    new ProductEntity {Name = "Second", Price = 2M},
                    new ProductEntity {Name = "Third", Price = 3M}
                };

                var productList = products
                   .Select(p => new {  p.Name, p.Price });

                Assert.That(productList, Is.Not.Null);
                Assert.That(productList.Count(), Is.EqualTo(3));
                Assert.That(productList.ElementAt(0), Has.No.Property("OtherProperty"));
                Assert.That(productList.ElementAt(0), Has.Property("Name"));

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps on GridView:

1. Disable `AutoGenerateColumns`
2. Click on GridView than "`Edit Columns`"
3. Add columns you want to show from your entity. e.g. add `BoundField`, it must contain `HeaderText` name of column you want to show, and `DataField` name of variable in your entity